# How to add an image to an existing table in a page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used a function like below to create the image. I'm sending in two variables: one for source link of an image and the other for its position to be embedded in the table. Actually, I want to create a div first and then keep image inside of that in "td" of the table, then add "br" tag after div so that existing "td" content comes in the next line.

```js
function createimage(src, k){
    console.log("got source as "+src);
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('width','200px');
    img.setAttribute('height','300px');
    img.src = src;
    img.setAttribute ('class', 'extarimages');
    document.getElementById("#destination tr:eq(1) td:eq("+(k+2)+")").appendChild(img);
    
    var mybr = document.createElement('br');
    document.getElementById("#destination tr:eq(1) td:eq("+(k+2)+")").appendChild(mybr);
}
```

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing dom queries to document.getElementById() as an argument, which is not allowed. If you want to do dom queries, use jQuery or similar javascript frameworks.

jQuery example:

```
$img = $('<img>').attr('src', src).attr('width', '200').attr('height', '300');    
$("#destination tr:eq(1) td:eq("+(k+2)+")").append($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would have done it:

Javascript:

```
function createimage(src, k){
    console.log("got source as "+src);
    var img= $(document.createElement('img'))
        .prop('src', src)
        .addClass("extarimages img-size");
    var tableCell = $("#destination tr:eq(1) td:eq("+(k+2)+")");
    $(tableCell).prepend(document.createElement('br'));
    $(tableCell).prepend(image);
}
```

CSS:

```
.img-size {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
  }
```

Notes:

You can create this new class, or just add the width and height in the existing *extarimages* class.

If you use < JQuery 1.6 use *attr()* instead of *prop()*